# Unable to get exact session time out value with db.session.commit()

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created little flask project with MySQL, which users sessions as well, now problem I am facing is that whenever I use `db.session.commit()`, it returns me current time for both session is and session out.

My Model for UserSession is like this:

```
class UserSessionModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_session'
    session_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    session_time_in = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    session_time_out = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

and Following is Users Model:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(90))
password = db.Column(db.String(80))
first_name = db.Column(db.String(40))
last_name = db.Column(db.String(40))
is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
last_updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

and for UserLogout, I am using following logic:

```
class UserLogout(Resource):
    @jwt_required()
    def post(self):
            jti = get_jwt()["jti"]
            BLOCKLIST.add(jti)
            email_address = get_jwt_identity()
            user_info = UserModel.find_by_email(email_address)
            user_id = user_info.id
            user_session = UserSessionModel.find_by_id_and_time_in(user_id).session_id
            user_session_info = UserSessionModel.find_by_session_id(user_session)
            user_session_info.session_time_out = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

            db.session.commit()
            session_info = UserSessionModel.find_by_user_id(user_id)
            revoked_token = RevokedTokenModel(jti=jti)
            revoked_token.add()
            return {
                'message': 'User Logged out',
                'user_Details': {
                    'email_address': email_address,
                    'user_session_id': user_session,
                    'user_session_time_in':  session_info.session_time_in.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                    'user_session_time_out': session_info.session_time_out.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                }
            }
```

Now if I commit, `db.session.commit()` line, I am getting correct `user_session_time_in` and `user_session_time_out`, I am getting correct values, but when uncommit it, and try to store it local database, I am getting current date and time on both parameters.

What possibly can be a problem.

Comment: What does "uncommit" mean?